# AS3 TextLineMetrics get text width BEFORE object is on Displaylist

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic-data, textfield

I have a library MovieClip Class that consists solely of a dynamic textfield contained in a MovieClip.

I want to instantiate this MC, populate the textField with text, get the width of the resulting text and, if the width is less than a predefined MIN_WIDTH value, append more text.

When the width is equal to or greater than my MIN_WIDTH value, add this MovieClip class to the display list.

My question is, does anyone know if its possible to retrieve the length of text in a textField using Textlinemetrics BEFORE the textField has been added to the display list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the following information, because text measurements work fine when you create and configure a text field, without ever adding it to the display list.

**The trick is to make sure you set the "text" property LAST, after fully configuring the TextField**.  Setting the "text" property seems to finalize the layout, given all the previously configured settings.

The problem you're encountering is probably that you're setting the "text" property and then making changes to other settings such as multiline or embedFonts.  When you do that, getLineMetrics will not return correct values.  If you then set the "text" property and check getLineMetrics again, the values will be correct.  See this example and the comments after the trace statements.

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat( "Arial Black", 16, 0, false );
tf.embedFonts = true;
tf.text = "Hello"; //set text last
trace( tf.getLineMetrics(0).height ); //Traces 22.55 (correct)

var tf2:TextField = new TextField();
tf2.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat( "Arial Black", 16, 0, false );
tf2.text = "Hello"; //set text first
tf2.embedFonts = true; //modify a property after setting text seems to make the TextField "dirty"
trace( tf2.getLineMetrics(0).height ); //Traces 1.15 (incorrect)

var tf3:TextField = new TextField();
tf3.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat( "Arial Black", 16, 0, false );
tf3.text = "Hello";
tf3.embedFonts = true; //modifying a property after setting the text seems to make the TextField "dirty"
tf3.text = "Hello"; //setting the text again seems to fix the problem
trace( tf3.getLineMetrics(0).height ); //Traces 22.15 (correct)
```

The lesson here is that the order you configure the TextField matters.  This is documented to be true, for example, with the defaultTextFormat property, which you must set BEFORE setting the text, otherwise the new text you set will not pick up the defaultTextFormat.  In that case, the text may not show up at all if you have embedFonts turned on and it uses some other default font that's not embedded.  So make sure you set the defaultTextFormat first, configure other properties, and set the "text" last, just before you call getLineMetrics.

Here, use this function I created.  It forces you to configure the important properties of the TextField first (text, type, multiline, selectable, embedFonts), and then the later parameters are exactly that of the TextFormat constructor, in the same order.  It ensures your properties are set in the correct order, the text is assigned last, and it will reduce your TextField creation down to one statement:

```
public static function CreateTextField( text:String = "", type:String = null, multiline:Boolean = false, selectable:Boolean = true, embedFonts:Boolean = false, font:String=null, size:Object=null, color:Object=null, bold:Object=null, italic:Object=null, underline:Object=null, url:String=null, target:String=null, align:String=null, leftMargin:Object=null, rightMargin:Object=null, indent:Object=null, leading:Object=null ):TextField
{
    var tf:TextField = new TextField();
    tf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat( font, size, color, bold, italic, underline, url, target, align, leftMargin, rightMargin, indent, leading );
    tf.embedFonts = embedFonts;
    tf.multiline = multiline;
    tf.selectable = selectable;
    tf.type = type;
    tf.text = text; //setting text last ensures the text line metrics returns correct values
    return tf;
}
```

Comment: When I copy and paste your code into Flash CS4 in the main timeline I'm not getting the same numbers.  I'm getting 0,1.15,0..

Comment: Then your font is not embedded.  You have to embed Arial Black in the library.  And if it's use count is zero, then you have to check "export for actionscript" to ensure the font is actually embedded.  Without embedding the font, you'll see 0 instead of 22.55.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - as far as I know, TextLineMetrics works regardless of whether a textfield is on the display list. Have you tried this and had trouble getting it to work? If so please let us know your code - unless I'm missing something it should just work.

Comment: It should definitely work, but you are missing something; see my answer.  I was running into this problem myself (which led me to this question), and saw that a very simple example I set up worked while the original did not.  The only difference between the two was the order of some statements, so I realized that if you set other properties such as "embedFonts" after setting the "text" property, getLineMetrics will return incorrect values.  So, you just have to set the "text" property last, after configuring the other properties, and then getLineMetrics will return correct values.